# Using dropdown names as variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, variables, drop-down-menu

I wants to use dropdown names as variable in asp.net webpage.

We have 10 dropdownlist with id- ddl1,ddl2,....ddl10. 
What my requirement is that i need to show and hide from the code behind file

```
    <div id ="divContainer" class="field" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fieldtxt">   
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" CssClass="fieldtxtbox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCommand_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    //like this 10 different DropDownList           
    </div>
```

i have certain loop for doing that.
i need something like this...

```
ddl[i].Visible = true;
```

when i tried this got error like

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Please help

Comment: Please post you HTML markup.

Comment: Find all DDL controls on your page. Iterate through that and set the visibility of the appropriate DDLs to true.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
DropDownList ddls = null;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    ddls = (DropDownList)this.FindControl("DropDownList" + i);
    if (ddls != null) {
        ddls.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The controls should be immediate children of the page. If these are embedded in other server control such as FormView, GridView etc or on Master page, then you must use that control or master in conjunction with FindControl

Answer (score 0):

```
Why not using javascript?

//save the div in a var
//check the name of the div in the generated html, it might be different from the name you have in asp.net

var divContainer = document.getElementById("divContainer");

//get all ddl contsols by Tag (tag for ddl is select)
var ddls = divContainer.GetElementByTag("select");

//iterate through the found select controls from the div and set them to visible

for (var i = 0, len = ddls.length; i < len; ++i)
{
     ddls[i].style.display='block';
}
```